# How to get AWStats report via email?

Tags: awstats

I have AWStats installed on a linux based machine and it just work fine.
Now, I want to get AWStats to send a report to my email.
I was thinking about writing a PHP script to call awstat.pl and then send an email with the report as an attachment. But I am not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It's a complex task.

Here they created a php script that is supposed to do the job you are asking for: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=275042

[Here is another script to enter into Awstats from outside cPanel](http://www.josheli.com/vox/).
This is a starting point, you could then complete the script by